# How to change vmin and vmax of each color with matplotlib imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an RGB image (N x N x 3 matrix) which I am trying to display with matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(). The red channel is dim compared to the others, but I have not found a way to change vmin and vmax only for the red. Is it possible to change the brightness/contrast of each channel? Maybe I could manipulate the matrix directly, but that does not sound too much fun..

Comment: What is the problem with manipulating the matrix. If your matrix `m` is `(N, N, 3)` and you have scaling and offset vectors `s` and `o` that are `(3,)`, the manipulation is `(m + o) * s` or `m * s + o` or something like that. Broadcasting is great that way.

Comment: Maybe I can just multiply the red channel by some value, or somehow normalize all channels. In my case, the pixel value can be negative. I would need to think about the variance and offset in each channel. It would be just more convenient if I could change the vmin and vmax of each channel.

Comment: Would you like me to write a three line function that will do it for you?

Comment: Also, what are `vmin` and `vmax` exactly here? Are you referring to the `clim` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulating images is really easy with numpy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qe6z.png")
print image.shape
print image.max()


def channelnorm(im, channel, vmin, vmax):
    c = (im[:,:,channel]-vmin) / (vmax-vmin)
    c[c<0.] = 0
    c[c>1.] = 1
    im[:,:,channel] = c
    return im

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(7,3))
ax.imshow(image)

vmin = 0.1
vmax = 0.5
channel = 0 # red
image2  = channelnorm(image, channel, vmin, vmax)
ax2.imshow(image2)

plt.show()
```

[image]